# Drupal Commerce USPS Module: Disable Shipping Services If Product Option Exists

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, usps, drupal-commerce

I need to disable all but one USPS shipping service (Parcel shipping) if any product in the cart has a certain custom product option (a checkbox) set.

I am a very good with Wordpress, but I am new to Drupal and cannot find a way to make this work.

What I've been trying is to set data comparison condition rules on each rate that I don't want to be available (Priority Shipping, etc). However, I can't seem to drill down to the products in the cart in order to check the product field value since I only have site: and commerce-order: root selectors available.

I am working with the latest version of Drupal and Commerce and USPS shipping modules.

Thanks for any help or direction!

Comment: You should be able to drill down but _Entity fields will only be available if you have used a condition to verify that the field is present or they are automatically exposed for that particular rule._ See [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/1300042) for more details.

Comment: At what point are you trying to disable the other shipping options? When products are added to the cart from the product page? On cart display/load?

Comment: I don't know enough about Drupal to know when the Data Comparison rules are ran, so I couldn't really answer that question. I don't personally care as long as it gets the job done. Why do you ask?